# In J2ME How to find the capability of emulator to check whether it can play certain media file or not

Tags: java-me, media-player, emulation, media, mmapi

In J2ME, How do I come to know that what is the capability of emulator to play certain media file though it is .mp3 or .wav or any other file

I am using Netbeans with WTK emulators & also nokia SDK 1.1.0 emulator....

Comment: try it and see? Or check the specifications?

Comment: (the comemnt this was a response to has been deleted). This is of course true. However in my experience you are better off doing your research in advance as it's difficult to get a single app to support a wide range of devices, hence the proliferation of targeted builds for groups of handsets. In addition I've also found that emulators do not necessarily have the full feature set that devices will have so testing on a emulator is never the final step.

Comment: @PaulC, yeah I deleted my comment, since I see you made yours before Rahul edited his question.  That said, it should be assumed that questions on Stack Overflow are asking about *programmatic* techniques.  Of course, you have to test your app on the devices you think you want to deploy to, but if you bundle multiple audio files in the final app, to avoid a ton of those targeted builds, you'd want to programmatically detect the host device's capabilities.

Comment: Ok PauL C... I will surely work on your suggestion... Thanx for the suggestion....

Comment: @Nate, indeed. I would note the question is only talking about emulators however and I'm really just saying that "emulators lie". It's their job. For example, video will be hardware accelerated on the device itself (perhaps) but the emulator will not be able to do that. So if it does not work on the emulator....

Comment: @PaulC, hard to say.  Earlier versions of the question did list *emulator or device*, and most people run apps on emulators so that they can later run the same apps on a device.  Whether an emulator is true to the device doesn't matter.  *Because* an emulator might not be able to support the same audio formats as your target device, you may need to programmatically test for audio file support.  Otherwise, you may find your app having problems running on the emulator, which would otherwise be a useful tool, simply because you didn't code to flexibly handle different levels of audio support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.  It uses the same [Manager API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#getSupportedContentTypes%28java.lang.String%29) that you used in your last question.

```
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
```

...

```
  String supportedTypes[] = Manager.getSupportedContentTypes(null);
  for (int i = 0; i < supportedTypes.length; i++) {
     if (supportedTypes[i].startsWith("audio")) {
        System.out.println("Device supports " + supportedTypes[i]);
     }
  }
```

running this for me produced the following output on a BlackBerry 9550:

```
[0.0] Device supports audio/x-tone-seq
[0.0] Device supports audio/midi
[0.0] Device supports audio/mpeg
[0.0] Device supports audio/x-wav
[0.0] Device supports audio/amr
[0.0] Device supports audio/x-gsm
[0.0] Device supports audio/mp4
[0.0] Device supports audio/aac
[0.0] Device supports audio/x-ms-wma
```

Comment: Whatever output you have post it is of proper WTK emulator or its only possible answers....

Comment: The output is just an example for a particular BlackBerry J2ME device.  You should run the actual Java **code** I posted on the device or emulator you're using, and it will tell you what media types that device/emulator supports.  Your results may list more, or fewer supported audio types.

Comment: I want to play .mp3 file by using player... so which string type i.e. x-tone-seq or else any other, should i pass to play .mp3 file. Right now I try to play one mp3 file whose size is 36.7 kb bit rate is 128 kpbs & duration is 0.00.02 but it gives me exception as "null"... So what should i do to play .mp3 file.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the string `"audio/mpeg"` means that .mp3 files are supported.  However, you cannot **tell** the device which formats to support.  It either supports mp3 or not.  You can only **ask** which formats are supported.  If the device doesn't support mp3, there's nothing you can do to play an mp3 file (aside from resaving it as some other format that is supported).

Comment: @Rahul, I double-checked, and `audio/mpeg` [is the correct content type for MP3 files](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003.txt).  So, if you use `Manager.createPlayer()`, that's the string to pass in.  However, as I said, that will only work if `audio/mpeg` is in the list of supported types ... I would hope that it would be, though.